# How to set an environment variable with another variable before calling a sub-process?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script like

```
# print.sh
# export FOO=test would work too
FOO=test ./foo-proj # Something that cares about FOO (shell script or just a binary)
```

This works. However, I'm wondering why if I do this...

```
#print.sh
blah="FOO=test"
$blah ./foo-proj
```

I get this error `./print.sh: line 2: FOO=test: command not found`. It's like bash is now interpreting `FOO=test` as a command instead of a variable declaration. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Welcome, you can do for example `FOO=echo; blah=FOO; ${!blah} foo → foo`, but I don't know if that's what you aim to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

```
env -- "$blah" ./foo-proj
```

There, that's env that calls `./foo-proj` with the contents of `$blah` in its environment. The advantage is that variable names in that case are not limited to valid shell variable names. For instance, you could have `blah='+++=xxx'` to pass an environment variable called `+++` even though `+++` is not a valid shell variable name.

```
(export -- "$blah"; exec ./foo-proj)
```

Or:

```
eval  " $blah ./foo-proj"
```

Where `eval` will be passed `" FOO=test ./foo-proj"` as one argument, and that string will then be evaluated as shell code (where the `=` will then be literal and therefore treated as an assigment).

Beware though that if `$blah` is `blah='FOO=test;reboot;'`, it will reboot for instance.

Comment: I've found using `bash -c "$blah ./foo-proj"` works too. Is this equivalent to `eval`?

Comment: That's like `eval`, but has the code run by a new separate invocation of the bash interpreter instead of the current one. So it's about as dangerous and less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case, bash doesn't detect the `$blah` as an environment variable, but rather as a command containing a `=`.

You need to do something like :

```
blah="test"
FOO=$blah ./foo-proj
```